# Sublime Text 2 Mouse free Opening files from "Find in Files" results

Tags: windows, sublimetext2

Loving Sublime Text 2.

What would be a huge help is being able to open a file from the **Find in File** results without using the mouse.

Can't find the shortcut for this; there must be one!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use F4, or Shift+F4 to navigate through search results list.

Comment: When on the search line press F4 as szarouski explains.

Comment: but is there a shortcut to get back to the search results?

Answer (score 8):

A day away and a fresh search I come up with [this page](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html) in the Sublime Text 2 documentation, which works.

Comment: but the navigation part in that page is empty :(
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html#navigating-results

Answer (score 3):

There is https://github.com/abrookins/OpenSearchResult which works fine for me in Vintage.